# 'npm install firebase' hangs in wsl. runs fine in windows

Tags: firebase, npm

npm intall started hanging in my wsl environment. For example the standard `npm install firebase` (Abusing firebase here so I can give the question a firebase tag. On the other hand I only use npm to work on a firebase web app).

Back to windows, installing and upgrading node/npm (npm version 8.5.5). `npm install firebase` ran exactly as expected.

The only change that might have an impact was adding an ssh-key for github. But my linux and npm level is too low to see how/why that breaks npm. Any hints and tips on where  and how to look for solutions to this issue appreciated. Thank you.